# Sorting Combinations according to the price prestashop

Tags: combinations, prestashop

I am new to prestashop I am facing a problem while sorting the product combinations according to their price. Until now I came to know to do it manually but I want it dynamic i.e if someone changes the price it should automatically sort in order.How can I achieve this?? Is there are some modules which provides this functionality or anything else.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Do you want to sort combinations by price in PrestaShop back-office -> Products -> Combinations?

Comment: My actual need is to see the sorted result of combination in the frontend. Any method that will work will be great.

Comment: Do you want to automatically make the cheapest product combination the default for each product?

Comment: Yes, and others combination in an increasing order

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want. On which page would you like to list the product combinations? Normally product combinations of a product are not listed on the frontend only the parent product. You can choose a specific product combination by selecting product attributes e.g., size, color on the product's page.

Answer (score 0):

I got it and was quite simple, my foolishness that i was making it difficult. Whatever the order of the combination in the backend, the combination in the frontend is displayed according to the sort order of the attribute. So to sort according to the cost of the combination attribute I just need to sort the attribute in "Attributes and Values".The way you sort the attributes in the "Attributes and Values" reflects the sorting in the frontend display.Hence fulfilling my requirement.